# How to fix "undefined" items while replacing values in a list

Tags: javascript

Objective: Identify which values are equal in list1 and list2 and replace those by random words in list 3, at end it's required to print a modified list2.

```
cconst list1 = [
    'AAAAAA',
    'BBBBBB',
    'CCCCCC',
    'DDDDDD',
    'EEEEEE'
];

const list2 = [
    'EEEEEE',
    '111111',
    'BBBBBB',
    '222222',
    '333333',
    'CCCCCC',
    '444444',
    'DDDDDD',
    '555555'
];
const list3 = [

    '666666',
    '777777',
    '888888',
    '999999'
];
```

My attempt to solve the problem:

```
list2.forEach((hash => (a, i, aa) => {
  if (hash.has(a)) {
    aa[i] = list3[i]
})(new Set(list2)));


console.log(list2);
```

The output I am getting:

```
[ '666666',
  '777777',
  '888888',
  '999999',
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined ]
```

Any tip how can I solve this?
Thanks ;)

Comment: list3 is much shorter than list2 so logic is flawed

Comment: Not hard to research how to get a random value from an array

Comment: the unique values in the list2 should remain, so the list3 being shorter does not matter at all

Comment: It certainly does matter when you attempt to get a matching index that doesn't exist in the shorter array. That is why you see all the `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Use whatever random generator you want for the value from list3 (easily researched).

One of the problems in your code  is you are overshooting the length of `list3`  which accounts for the `undefined`.

Following is just using modulo of the larger array index compared to length of list3.

```js
const res = list2.map((el,i) => list1.includes(el) ? list3[i % list3.length] : el);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script>
const list1 = [
    'AAAAA',
    'BBBBB',
    'CCCCC',
    'DDDDD',
    'EEEEEE'
];

const list2 = [
    'EEEEEE',
    '111111',
    'BBBBBB',
    '222222',
    '333333',
    'CCCCCC',
    '444444',
    'DDDDDD',
    '555555'
];

const list3 = [
    '666666',
    '777777',
    '888888',
    '999999'
];
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like a very interesting solution, will analyze it and try to learn from it, thank you very much!!!

Comment: If you expand this out you can set a  variable for `i % list3.length` and see the values it returns. Any random generator has to consider the length to return a valid index